# Question-connected bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $M=\{ m_1, \dots , m_r\}$ and $N=\{ n_1, \dots , n_l \}$,where $r,l \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } 1 \leq r \leq l $.
It is also given that $G$ is a coherent bipartite graph,with sets of vertices $N$ and $M$.

Is the diameter equal to $2$,OR between:

-$2r$ and $2l$

-$r$ and $l$

-$2$ and $2r$

-$2$ and $r$

Answer (score 1):

$$|M|=r\leq l=|N|$$

Since $G$ is bipartite, the longest possible path is the path that starts and ends in $N$ and contains all of the vertices of $M$. So if the path looks like $(n_1,m_1,...,m_r,n_k)$ where $r\leq k$, you could travel through maximally $2r$ edges because you have to enter and exit every vertex of $M$.

Comment: But since the graph is connected ,isn't there an edge between all$ a_i$ and $b_j$,so $d(a_i,b_j)=1$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily. Connectivity of a graph tells us only that there is a path between every two $x,y \in V$. If all $a_i$ were connected with all $b_j$ the graph would be complete and btw. complete graph (except $K_2$) can't be bipartite.

Comment: And from what I know, the definition of diameter is "the longest shortest path", not "the shortest". Of course the shortest possible distance between 2 vertices in a connected graph is $1$ (or $0$, when there is only one vertex).

Comment: Shouldn't the path contain also all of the vertices of $N$ since the graph is connected?

Comment: No, because since the graph is bipartite, there are no edges between any vertices in $N$ (because $N$ and $M$ are both independent sets).

Comment: We shouldn't an edge start from $b_{r+1}$ ?

Comment: I think that firstly you should understand all the definitions (make some sketches if there's something you don't get). Your question was (translated from maths to English): "What is the length of the longest possible path in a connected bipartite graph with given sets of vertices $N$ and $M$ where $|M|\leq |N|$." And the answer is as I gave you. I don't know what else should I tell you. A path is a sequence of vertices where every two vertices are distinct from each other.

Comment: Oops...Now I see that $G$ is a coherent bipartite graph and not a connected bipartite graph. Is there a difference now?

Comment: But from what I know, coherent is just another word to say connected, so no, there's no difference to what I wrote earlier. Look at the definition of connectivity (or coherence): graph $G=(V,E)$ is connected if and only if there is a $x-y$ path for every $x,y\in V$.

Comment: I see. Does the longest possible path start and end at the nodes of the same sets? You said that the path looks like $(n_1,m_1, \dots, m_r, n_k)$. So the initial node and the last node are both from the set $N$. Do it have to be so or does this hold only because in that way the path is longer? An other question: Since the graph is coherent, shouldn't the nodes $n_r, n_{r+1}, \dots , n_{k-1}, n_{k+1}, \dots, n_l$ be also at the path?

Comment: If we start in N, the path will be longest. Assume it wasn't and you want to start in $M$. You know that $|M|\leq |N|$. Your path will look (at most) like: $(m_1,n_1,...,n_{r-1},m_r)$ so clearly there is less vertices in this path (because you will always use at max one less vertice from $N$ than from $M$ if you start in M). And you can't construct a path like $(n_r,n_{r+1},...)$ because the graph is bipartite and that means that there are NO edges between any two vertices in $N$.